# Filter document to match either of the two fields in nested elasticsearch field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I have a field named tags in my document in elasticsearch with the following structure.

```
tags = [
    {
        "id": 10,
        "related": [9, 8, 7]
    }
]
```

I now run a filter with a list. e.g. `[10, 9]`. I want to filter only those documents which contain all the items in the list either in id or in related. If I search with `[9, 8]`, the above document should be returned. If I search with `[9, 12]`, the above document shouldn't be returned as 12 isn't present in either id or related.

I tried with terms filter but it simply does or. Is there any technique that can be implemented to achieve the above goal.

Further, I would like to provide a higher ranking to document which contain the given items in id compared to those which contain given items in `related`.

Comment: Is `tag` a nested field?

Comment: can you share your mappings of the index?

Comment: Hi @Sudip, have you checked my answer? was it helpful?

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem Analysis

Let's break your problem in the following subproblems:

- **(P1)** Check whether *all* the terms provided in the array are present in either `tags.id` or `tags.related`. This can be further decomposed into:

  - **(P1.1)** Check whether *all* the terms provided in the array are present in a field
  - **(P1.2)** Check whether *all* the terms provided in the array are spread across different fields
- **(P2)** Assign a higher score to those documents having any of the provided terms as `tags.id`

---

#### Solution

To solve **(P1.1)**, you can use the `terms_set` query, available in Elasticsearch v6.6 (see [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html)).

To solve **(P1.2)**, I'd copy all the values of `tags.id` and `tags.related` into a new custom field, named, e.g., `tags.all`. This can be achieved using the `copy_to` property as follows:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "tags": {
          "properties": {
            "id": { 
              "type": "long",
              "copy_to": "tags.all"
            },
            "related": { 
              "type": "long",
              "copy_to": "tags.all"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, to solve **(P1)**, you can run your `terms_set` query against `tags.all`. E.g.,

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms_set": {
      "tags.all": {
        "terms": [ 9, 8 ],
        "minimum_should_match_script": {
          "source": "2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, to solve **(P2)**, you can create a boolean `should` query that includes (i) the `terms_set` query described above, (ii) a `terms` query against `tags.id` only, which has a higher boost factor. I.e.,

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms_set": {
            "tags.all": {
              "terms": [ 9, 8 ],
              "minimum_should_match_script": {
                "source": "2"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "tags.id": {
              "value": [ 9, 8 ],
              "boost": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```